# I'm generating random integers in Excel using the NORMINV function. Is there any way to set an upper and lower limit to the generated numbers?

Tags: excel, statistics

I am simulating data in MS Excel. The scenario is small business call data. I need to generate about 3000 integers with a mean average of 24.16, that fall on a normal (or lognormal?) statistical distribution. Because the scenario is call data, I can't have any values in my data set smaller than 0 or larger than 540 (Can't have calls with a negative wait time and after 540 seconds the call goes to voicemail).

The upper and lower bounds have really been throwing me. Almost all the solutions I've seen so far include just generating a normal distribution and then throwing out results outside the required range, failing to preserve the bell curve.

I've already tried:

=ROUND(NORMINV(RAND(),K$1,L$1),0)
Where K1 is a cell that contains my Mean (24.16) and L1 my standard deviation. This method results in negative numbers, I can't limit it with an upper or lower bound.

=LOGINV(RAND(),K$1,L$1)
This generates absolutely enormous numbers that are totally useless to me, I suspect because I'm doing something wrong with the mean. I've tried to research a way to generate a mean that this formula will accept, but they involve sampling from data you already have, which I don't.

I see that there are some other people who have grappled with similar problems using R, but I have no experience with R and would need some pretty extraordinary hand holding to be able to implement any sort of solution in R. I'm hoping to have the data sample I need by the end of the week.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-model-normal-distribution-with-upper-max-and-lower-min-in-Excel

Comment: I suspect call wait times are not well-modeled by either normal or lognormal distributions, and also it could be a little tricky to wedge one or the other of them into place, given the constraints. Maybe the easiest path forward is to get a sample of call wait times and resample it, maybe adding jitter. Then you're guaranteed the distribution has the right shape.